# Thevenin's equivalent of Wheatstone bridge

Tags: resistance, thevenin

I tried to calculate the Vos and Isc and both of them are zero..so the Thevenin's resistance is 0/0=undefined. How do I calculate the resistance when Vos/Isc fails,such like the Wheatstone bridge?Besides short-circuiting voltage sources and open-circuiting current sources, because that's a way only if my sources are all independent.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve beyond the thevenin stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Apply an arbitrary voltage across the terminals (say, v<sub>ab</sub> = 1V) and find i<sub>ab</sub>. Then, use the formula v<sub>ab</sub> = v<sub>oc</sub> - i<sub>ab</sub>R<sub>t</sub> and solve for the Thevenin resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Better to try with an arbitrary one ampere current source across terminals. Then using kvl , you can find V. Then R = v/i. You will find a surprise r value.